# hiding login fields from google search

Tags: html, schema.org, search-engine-bots

**Background:** 
My website allows registered users to upload and share videos.

On the main page there is a "Username" and "Password" field so that registered users can log in if they wish.

Also, on each video page, there are text links to choose bitrate and flash player.

(See http://videoflier.com/ and http://videoflier.com/movies/1360488842878341996730 for examples of both.)

or search google for "site:videoflier.com" to see what I'm talking about.

**My Problem:** 
When google or any search engine indexes it, they of course see the login text and the links for setting the video bitrate (which look like " 190 234 [698] 1247 kbps | osflv [jwplayer] flowplayer ")

(Search google for "site:videoflier.com" to see example.)

It looks like this:

Cardboard Airplane
videoflier.com/movies/1352509017371554759177
Cardboard Airplane By jesseg 190 234 [698] kbps | osflv jwplayer [flowplayer] This is a model airplane built from cardboard and tape. It was outfitted with remote ...

(Notice how the bitrates and player selections look ugly and waste space.)

**My attempts to solve so far in a clean tidy manner**
(And why I don't like any of them.)

***Using pictures instead of text:*** I want my site to be fast and efficient, so I don't want to use pictures for text if I don't have to.

***Having a separate page for settings:*** I want the site to be fast and simple to use.

***robots.txt:*** If the search engines can't read the pages then it won't know how to find them!

***Using CGI to hide stuff from search bots*** This is about the best idea I've had - but I don't really want to do a dirty hack, and it seems there's no universal way for my CGI to identify a robot. Google themselves uses several different user-agent strings, none of which actually contain the word "robot." Most contain "Googlebot" but not all. And who knows what other search engines use.

Of course I understand (and google makes this very claim) why they use agent strings that look like regular web browsers -- because dishonest folks try to send completely different content to the search engine for ad fraud.

But I don't really want to have to essentially run a continually changing blacklist to try to identify all possible search engines out there. Sounds too much like fighting email spam. And besides, I'm just trying to hide the login and bitrate lists so the search results are easier to read.

***javascript:*** Javascript brings its own problems (Browser compatibility issues, accessibility, etc.)  I use it when it is the best tool for the job, but I really love pure clean HTML when I can have it.

***In an ideal world:*** I wish I had an HTML tag that goes like <NOBOT>username: password:</NOBOT> -- but as far as I know, nothing exists. Ideally, this fictitious tag would also keep the search engines from returning results based on the hidden items. Somebody who puts the word "password" into google most certainly is not trying to find my site -- and yet google may return it simply because it has a login field on it.

***schema.org?*** I initially had hopes for schema.org because it allows one to specify the type of data within scopes in the HTML. Unfortunately, as far as I could tell, all of its categories and things are for things that are: It didn't seem to have a "Ignore" or "Administrative object" option.

Maybe the more round about answer is to use schema.org extensively for everything else so the search engines already know where to get their author, description, and title text from, then maybe they will skip the administrative control links.

Thank you very much,

Jesse Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I would think it makes more sense to add a meta description to your pages.

For for example:
Cardboard Airplane videoflier.com/movies/1352509017371554759177 Cardboard Airplane By jesseg 190 234 [698] kbps | osflv jwplayer [flowplayer] This is a model airplane built from cardboard and tape. It was outfitted with remote ...

I would just add this to your header section.
   `<meta name="description" content="This is a model airplane built from cardboard and tape. It was  outfitted with remote control and servos so it could be flown as an RC glider.
It did fly but had a tendency to stall. " />`

Comment: The user can type in (or paste) in as long an HTML description as they please. It could be several pages, if they wanted. Are you suggesting that my page contain the full description twice -- once for the search engine and a second time for the users? I guess that would work.  I wonder if it would really cause google (and others) to ignore the administrative link text. Thanks!

Comment: I've applied the tagging described here http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2413309  and I will see how that works.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.  Search engines are smart, so they know what data is important. So, changing the description won't alter your search ranking. But, if you are wanting to control what shows up as a description in a search engine, then make that information be in the search meta tag.